# Proportionally resizing a full-screen image using "supersized" jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) to display images in full screen.

You can see a sample here (on homepage): http://mysampleconcept.com/situs4/

If you try to shrink the screen, you will notice that the image will resize too, however it may shrink too much that the image will look bad.

The same plugin is used here as well: http://mysampleconcept.com/situs3/; however, the resizing is done differently so the image doesn't go out of proportions.

I have tried to compare the plugins settings on both sites and they both seem to be similar.

I have tried setting the image width and height to `100% !important` in my css and it didn't help.

Any suggestion on how to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: i think they are using background:cover ... i dug into their code - but couldn't get all the way to the bottom of it --- also - if you try go down the img 100% road... try out height or width 100% and then the other one auto --- not both 100% or it will stretch...

Comment: The background is not applied to the body element or any other element, so I can't use the background-size: cover property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is from the common css that does your image all base on "max-width:100%".

Check your css reset if there is something like

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

The supersized official has a solution for the file "supersized.3.2.7.js":
https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/issues/103

If you can not solve it by following the official solution, try only add this in your supersized css:

```
#supersized img { max-width: none; }
```

this tricky is by http://blog.valderama.net/node/30

Answer (score 0):

When I removed

```
 #supersized img {
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}
```

it seems to work.

Comment: It works, but as I described above, the behavior is not the same for the same image on both sites. Try resizing the "big ben" image on both sites, and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an optimal solution, I was able to solve this by adding `min-width` and `min-height` to the supersized image